# Trying to understand SATA cables

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I have a PC someone else built for me a few years ago, and as I have been upgrading it slowly I have been learning new things and how to properly care for a PC. I still don't know everything.

I have a brand new laptop HDD lying around and I would like to plug it into my desktop. I do not know how this works so I looked at the cables and I believe I have figured some things out, but there are other things I still do not understand.

From what I can see and deduce, a HDD needs two connections in order to work: data and power. I have found a free cable hanging from the PSU and it fits perfectly in my HDD  However, I cannot find a free data cable. Following my SSD and HDD cables, I found they are both connected to the motherboard in white... sockets? plugs? Thingy. From a web search, I believe these are called SATA cables, abd there are only two of them. Besides them, I can also see two empty black sockets and one empty brown socket.

My question is this: what is the cable I need in order to plug my new HDD in? I would purchase another "SATA III" cable, but it doesn't look like there is room for another. What are the black and brown sockets on my motherboard for?

For reference, I'm using an older Sabertooth Z77 motherboard.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: From Wikipedia, this is [power cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SATA_power_cable.jpg) and [data cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SATA_Data_Cable.jpg).

Comment: From what I've figured, this seems to match my deductions, so I think I am on the right track. However, both white SATA sockets on my motherboard were already in use, and the only other things next to them were two black sockets and one brown one. Can I use these three to plug SATA cables?

Comment: From the manual, those SATA connectors differs in SATA speed. Get manual from here https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z77/HelpDesk_Manual/.

Answer (score 2):

**You are on the right track.**

As stated before by harrymc you can find information on the ports on the [website of your motherboard manufacturer](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z77/specifications/):

> Intel® Z77 chipset :
>
> 2 x SATA 6Gb/s port(s), brown,
>
> 4 x SATA 3Gb/s port(s), black,
>
> [...]
>
> ASMedia® ASM1061 controller : *5
>
> 2 x SATA 6Gb/s port(s), gray,
>
> 2 x eSATA 6Gb/s port(s), red,

Comparing your statement with this information, the **"white" ports** are most likely what ASUS describes as "gray" ports **connected to the ASM1061 storage controller**. With the **brown (SATA III) and black (SATA II) connectors** being directly wired into the **Z77 chipset**. **For a HDD it should not matter to much**, but in theory the **fastest ports should be the brown ones** (as they don't take the additional step through the storage controller) closely followed by the gray/white ports, the slowest beeing the black ones (but still fast enought for a HDD).

I'd therefore recommend you to **buy a SATAIII data cable** (or ask a friendof yours for one if they have lying some of them around, as from my experience it's quite expensive per cable to buy them in low quantities) and **plug the HDD into one of the empty ports**.

You might also consider to take a look at which drive is currently connected to which port and consider reordering them with the fastest (and most often used) drive connected to the fasted port (brown > white > black) but this is not necessary (and might change the drive letters even though that has never happened to me).

If you wonder: *The red ports are external SATA and therefore most likely positioned next to your other external connectors on the back of your PC. Those are mostly not in widespread use anymore and not helpful for this problem, if you don't want the drive connected externally.*

Answer (score 0):

From
[ASUS SABERTOOTH Z77](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z77/specifications/):

[image]

Your colors differ from the manual, so I'm not at all sure that you have the
Sabertooth Z77 motherboard. But I would still guess that the two white sockets are
the only SATA 6Gb/s ports on this motherboard.

Comment: I am guessing the “white” ports are the gray ports, the motherboard doesn’t have white ports, so that’s the only explanation